# How to exclude a file extension from IntelliJ IDEA search?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to exclude particular file extension from the results in IntelliJ IDEA's "*Find in Path*" dialog (invoked by <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>)? I want to exclude all `.css` files.

Answer (score 325, accepted):

In intellij 16 there is a section "File name Filter" to exclude an extension use `!*.java`. You can give more detailed patterns as well for example I use the pattern below to only return .java files except those with a name starting or ending with test.
Pattern: `!*test.java,*.java,!Test*.java`

[image]

In recent versions of Intellij the GUI has been updated a bit but the same still applies see the "File mask" on the top right hand corner see image below:

[image]

Comment: Can I not mention !mocks/*.json in the File Masks filter ?

Comment: @CodeTweetie what are your doing to do with the '/' not sure why its needed (i thought '/' is just a delimiter in regex). without it your filter would say exclude any file that starts with "mock"s followed by anything ending in ".json"

Comment: This "File name Filter" dialogue doesn't seem to exist in recent versions (2018.1, etc.).

Comment: Note that this feature was added in IntelliJ 2016.1. If you're using a perpetual fallback license of IntelliJ 15 or older, this feature won't be available. [See my other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262526/intellij-file-mask-not-working-on-simple-excluding-file-pattern-why/55130341#55130341)

Comment: For anybody who's interested, this works in Rider as well.

Comment: For php 2018, this option is in Settings > Editor > File Types > Ignore files and folders (at the bottom).  It also uses standard positive/inclusion patterns (use \*.sql to exclude sql files instead of !\*.sql etc).

Answer (score 99):

In "Find in Path" and "Find in Files" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) you can use the "File mask" input.

For example, this would exclude all js, css and twig:

```
!*.js, !*.css, !*.twig
```

[image: PhpStorm File Masks for Find in Path]

It's handy cause it also keeps a list of previous inputs, but it gets messy easily when you add a lot of extensions. If it gets too crowded, consider excluding some folders as well (right-click -> "Mark directory as" -> "Excluded")

Comment: Frustrating that this is not documented anywhere in the docs but this is exactly what I wanted

Comment: it does not work for me, it only takes the 1st filter, am using intellij 2022.2.4 ultimate edition

Answer (score 59):

You can create custom scope there:
In 'Find in Path' dialog you can check radio button 'Custom' and open scopes window.
There you can customize path and search pattern.

[image]

Examples of Patterns for `Pattern` field:

- `!file:*.css` - exclude CSS files
- `file[MyMod]:src/main/java/com/example/my_package//*` - include files from the directory in a project.
- `src[MyMod]:com.example.my_package..*` - recursively include all files in a package.
- `file:*.js||file:*.coffee` - include all JavaScript and CoffeeScript files.
- `file:*js&&!file:*.min.*` - include all JavaScript files except those that were generated through minification, which is indicated by the min extension.

Or check the official [documentation.](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/scope-language-syntax-reference.html)

Good luck!

Comment: So what is the pattern to exclude all CSS style sheets?

Comment: Sorry, it's in IntelliJ's documentation: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/scope-language-syntax-reference.html. For excluding CSS it's: !file:*.css.

Comment: You made my day! Finally, I can to exclude annoying test-cases.js

Answer (score 25):

If you are like me that don't want to use the File Mask option or create a custom scope, etc. but just wanted to be able to add it to project settings one time and be done with it, then here's a solution for you.

I wanted my **Find in Path** to not search in `lock` files (auto-generated manifest file by package managers), here's what I had to do for that:

Goto *File >> Project Structure* (or just press Command+;)

Select Modules under **Project Settings**

[image]

Add a pattern or file names to the Exclude files text-box, in this case: `*.lock;package-lock.json` and hit Apply, and then ok.

[image: intellij-project-structure-screenshot]

**Note** The above option is available in **IntelliJ 2019** and versions after that, not sure about older versions. For more info, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/excluding-files-from-project.html

Comment: The problem with this is that it also excludes files with those extensions from the build right, not just from searches!?

Comment: @Suan as far as I know, it will only exclude the file from searches, code completion, inspections, etc. pretty much excluded from indexing. Checkout this article from JetBrains, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/excluding-files-from-project.html

Comment: The description is not good. It took me 5 minutes to find find this option in Project Structure. Please add another screenshot showing where exactly to find this.

Comment: @ArunKarnati Great! Thanks!

Comment: Once you click on a module, you have to click "Sources" for "Exclude files" to appear.

Comment: This is a proper answer. Thank you!

Comment: Many thanks, it works well, so many time lost at filtering this *.lock files. No it's over. Many love on you

Answer (score 8):

**WebStorm 2021**

CTRL+SHIFT+F and follow the pictures

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For 2019.2, the pattern is not set in scope but in the right top windows "File mask" in `Find in path` dialog. You must tick it.

The syntax I tested are:

- exclude files with extension `css`: `!*.css`
- exclude all under `out` dir: `!out/*`

Patterns are separated by comma.

Reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html

Answer (score 3):

For 2021.3.2, just right-click to the folder and Mark Directory as -> Excluded. This will work for logs etc but be careful about source folders.