# How do you exclude file types of IntelliJ find?

Tags: intellij-idea

My find settings look like the below:

[image]

Currently, I'm able to specify which file types to include in the search, but can't seem to find the same thing for file types to exclude when searching. How is this done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22143881/1291150

Comment: Since the 14 version of IntelliJ, most of the documentation has become invalid, and pretty much most of the UI looks very different

Comment: Yeah, but this part seems to look almost the same in 14. And the Jetbrains documentation on scopes seems up to date also... so you should have your answer: Create custom scope as described by to the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/scopes.html)

Answer (score 0):

To exclude files using the file name filter use a `!` in the mask. For example `!*.html` to exclude html filers. See also [the help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/find-and-replace-in-path.html#d1277847e247)