# IntelliJ File mask not working on simple excluding file pattern! Why?

Tags: search, text, intellij-idea, intellij-15, filepattern

Follows this page https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/find-and-replace-in-path.html?origin=old_help#mask , it should be able to exclude many files using "!" symbol in front of the regular pattern like: *.java, when doing text search inside IntelliJ projects.

On my project, when I fired <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to do text search for string xyz. There's over 100+ results return in both *.ftl and *.java files. I tried to reduce the results on only ftl files by changing the "File mask(s)"-Option to "`!*.java`" . But it did not work! The result list is empty!

Googling on the excluding file pattern results in creating custom file filters for each particular search, which I don't want to maintain!

Do I miss something here or IntelliJ is just bad on this function (I'm using IntelliJ 15)? With Eclipse, the "File mask" was amazing!

Answer (score 14):

You have to use 
`!*.java` instead of `!.java`

Answer (score 4):

As for IDEA 2019.1 Ultimate, it works for me(exclude with `!*.yml` or anything else).

If it does not in yours, as you only as `.ftl` file to exclude, why not add mask as `*.java`?

PS: what does not work is exclude some path, like "all files under `out/` folder". With `!out/*` or anything ales it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about File Mask and use Scope:

[image: scope image]

In Scope the options are unlimited where you can select folder include/exclude files or folders.

Comment: This was useful for me when I wanted to find and replace in non-test files.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding file paths in the Find in Path dialogue [was not added until IntelliJ 2016.1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23316) per this [IntelliJ forum response](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207294815-Find-and-Replace-in-Path-Exclude-Test-Files-).