# Exclude files with certain extensions while searching in IntelliJ IDEA using File maks

Tags: regex, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, is it possible to limit search to files that exclude a certain extension? For example, I want to search for VirtualService among all non-yaml files. Do I need a regex to achieve this?

[image]

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22143881/how-to-exclude-a-file-extension-from-intellij-idea-search

Answer (score 1):

In file path it is possible to exclude several file extensions, for example:

`!*yml, !*yaml`

This will exclude all .yml and .yaml file from search results.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately this is not possible because there is no RegEx support.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-183.5153.38, built on January 9, 2019

Comment: chance too vote for that https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-186851