# How to exclude specific file (full path or relative path) from search

Tags: intellij-idea

I have specific file generated after build under sub module abc/xyz.yml, how to exclude that specific file in specific module but not all yml file when searching in intellij?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In file mask (on the top right corner) you can search only in one file with `xyz.yml`, search for multiples files with `*.yml` or `xyz.yml, abc.yml` and you can inverse this search with an exclamation mark `!xyz.yml`

Comment: First I want to add these specific files permanently. This answer quite match but I want to add specific file instead of *.yml: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57317891/5419748

Comment: Another solution I think have to create custom filter: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37781104/5419748 but this is not so convenient

Comment: I don't think I can create custom filter, so have to input the file every time searching?

Comment: @ZxbinhjyxZ I don't know for custom filter but as I said, you can make specific filters with `name_of_file.yml` or exclude it with `!name_of_file.yml`

Comment: hi @ Marius ROBERT, there are 5 files I want to exclude, every time I search I have to input manually 5 files? and more important point is I want to exclude file in specific module (there are 2 file with same name, exclude only in 1 sub module), can I filter file with the sub module also?